# Text in <p> not displayed entirely (?)

Tags: css, wordpress

If you take a look at [this link](http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/history) you'll see text in the second slide. This text is purposely *very* (for testing purposes) long but only a very small part of it is being displayed in the `<p>` tag.

If you look at the source, you'll notice that the entire text is indeed there but for some reason only a part is being rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put the pertinent code into the question here so that it will be useful for future vistors (when you take that link down)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the containing `<li>` and `<ul>` elements have a height specified and `overflow` is set to `hidden`

Press F12 in Internet Explorer 9 or Chrome to see the applied CSS

Comment: I fixed it, ty. I don't get why it was being displayed entirely because the height of the content was still within the height of the UL and LI which had the overflow: hidden attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a carousel plugin, this will slide the text in from the right.

The element will have a parent container that will have `overflow:hidden` CSS attribute; therefore until the carousel plugin alters the inner positions, it won't be displayed.